# How to "select" values with conditional from python mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

I want select values `gia_tri` = 0.9386137840266288, `sort` columns `ngay_tao ASCENDING` and Count all rows in database.
Then `COUNT` time query execute success.
I write code like but it's error:

```
import sys
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time
import random
import pymongo


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client.random
collection = db.randomData

inserted_documents_count = 0

start_time = datetime.now();

cursor = db.random.find({
        ("gia_tri": "0.9386137840266288"),
        ("ngay_tao", pymongo.ASCENDING)
    })

for document in cursor:
    inserted_documents_count = collection.count()
    print 'Co ', inserted_documents_count, ' documents trong database Random.'  
    print(document)

print 'Have ', inserted_documents_count, ' rows selected in ', (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds(), 's'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `cursor = db.random.find({
>           ("gia_tri": "0.9386137840266288"),
>           ("ngay_tao", pymongo.ASCENDING)
>       })`

The sorting part should go in a [separate `sort` argument](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find):

```
cursor = db.random.find(filter={"gia_tri": "0.9386137840266288"}, 
                        sort={"ngay_tao", pymongo.ASCENDING})
```

---

Also, you don't need to call the `collection.count()` inside the loop, do it once:

```
inserted_documents_count = collection.count()
cursor = db.random.find(filter={"gia_tri": "0.9386137840266288"}, 
                        sort={"ngay_tao", pymongo.ASCENDING})

for document in cursor:
    print 'Co ', inserted_documents_count, ' documents trong database Random.'  
    print(document)
```

Note that if you want to count only the filtered documents, you can call `count()` on the `cursor`:

```
inserted_documents_count = cursor.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still the option:

```
cursor = db.random.find({"gia_tri":"0.9386137840266288"}).sort("ngay_tao", 1)

for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```